# TeamCity fails to build Angular 5/ Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity

I have a project in VS 2017,  it is using 4.5.1 framework and I have the Angular 5 inside.   Problem is that for the people doing deployments, they are not having any issue with a Web API project getting build and Deployed with TeamCity,  only with my Angular5 project.

I see these error.

```
 Cannot start build runner, exit code - 11 (new)
```

Then

```
Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to detect default target(s) in the project file C:\BuildAgent\work\9893893\C2NG.Web.csproj
```

then

```
Please define targets explicitly in the build configuration options on TeamCity Web UI.
```

And

```
Project does not define DefaultTargets or InitialTarget
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It seems that you are using /target switch in your console command line. Please, try to specify target(s) that you need in the build configuration options on TeamCity Web UI, as it is suggested by the error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041168/teamcity-failed-to-detect-target-in-msbuild-project

Comment: How about the result when you build and Deployed project with Visual Studio or MSBuild command line on local? If it works fine, you may need to provide the configuration on teamcity, if it also not work on local, please share us the command line you build the project or some steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Tom Stickel, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you mind let us to know latest status of this issue?

Comment: didn't get a chance to look let.

Comment: shouldn't angular project be of their own type (rather than csproj) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `msbuild`command line tool, and should use `dotnet`, if you don't use the last version opf teamcity, you may use a simple command line runner.

You have the parameters at the official documentation for dotnet build:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x

```
dotnet build [<PROJECT>] [-c|--configuration] [-f|--framework] [--force] [--no-dependencies] [--no-incremental] [--no-restore] [-o|--output] [-r|--runtime] [-v|--verbosity] [--version-suffix]
```